# Options disappeared from the Mouse & Touchpad settings

Tags: fedora, gnome, mouse

This is what the *Settings > Mouse & Touchpad* page looks like on my Fedora 24 machine:
[image]

It only shows the primary key setting. All other settings, e.g., scroll sensitivity and double-click speed, are missing. The page should look much more like this: http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/here-s-what-the-gnome-control-center-app-will-look-like-in-gnome-3-22-and-later-504351-2.jpg

*How can I bring back the options?*
I have recently upgraded from Fedora 23 to 24. Could that be related?

Comment: Do you have `libinput` installed?

Comment: Yes, the installed packages with `libinput` in their name are `libinput.x86_64` and `xorg-x11-drv-libinput.x86_64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue after upgrading to Fedora 24.

I've found the answer here:
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=310515&page=2

Try removing the Xorg X11 Synaptics touchpad input driver:

```
sudo dnf remove xorg-x11-drv-synaptics
```

Then logout and login back again.